# Solving an integral equation: $y(x) = 16+\int_0^x 2t \sqrt{y(t)} dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I solve the following integral equation?

> $$y(x) = 16+\int_0^x 2t \sqrt{y(t)} dt$$

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$y(x) = 16+\int_0^x 2t \sqrt{y(t)} dt \tag{$\star$}$$
From fundamental theorem of calculus,
$$y'(x) = 2x \sqrt{y(x)} \implies \dfrac{dy}{y^{1/2}} = 2x dx \implies 2y^{1/2} = x^2 + \text{ constant}$$
Hence, we get that
$$y = \left(\dfrac{x^2+ c}2 \right)^2$$
Now plug this into $(\star)$ to determine the constant $c$.

Comment: After differentiating, shouldn't you make sure that any non-zero solution $y$ cannot take value 0? (that would come from the Cauchy-Lipstchitz Theorem: if $y(x)=0$ for some $x$, then $y'(x)=0$ and then $y\equiv 0$.

Comment: @ClementC. I see the issue when dividing by $\sqrt{y(x)}$, it should be non-zero. However, I don't see why $y(x) = 0$ for some $x$ then $y'(x) = 0$ implies $y(x) = 0$. For instance, $y(x) = x^4/4$ is a solution to $y'(x) = 2x\sqrt{y(x)}$. Also, there is a factor $1/2$ infront of $x^2$.

Comment: @ClementC. But $\sqrt y$ isn't Lipschitz continuous around $0$.

Comment: @GitGud: you mean, in order to apply the C-L Theorem? (I have to say the hypothesis of the theorem are a bit blurry in my mind).


user17762: that would come from the theorem, saying that the EDP $y'=f(x,y)$ with conditions $y(x_0), y'(x_0)=(a,b)$ ensures unicity of the solution on a maximal interval around $x_0$. But I'm no longer sure we can apply this theorem, after Git Gud's answer; but the argument that $y$ cannot take value $0$ should still be made.

Comment: @ClementC. Yeah, I meant in order to apply C-L T. I just checked the hypothesis on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) though.

Comment: @GitGud: but $\sqrt{\ }$ is still regular enough on the neighborhood on any $x_0 > 0$; so one can argue with the C-L theorem that $y(x_0)\neq 0$ for any $x_0>0$ (is that correct?

Additionally, from the question, I assumed that $y$ was from $\mathbb{R}_+$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (is that correct?)

Comment: so is the answer x^4/4?

Comment: @ClementC. I would assume $y : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_0^+$.